# Does the Kal calendar framework still work in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, calendar, ios5

I haven't implemented it yet, but I'm just wondering. If not, are there any other calendar frameworks that work in iOS 5?

Comment: I would assume so. The EventKit framework hasn't changed much since it was introduced, and iOS 5 was no exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works with `iOS5`.

I am new to `Objective C` and `iOS` but I did get it to display a calendar now I am working on displaying the table underneath.